# Arduino Nano not recognized on Windows 10

Tags: arduino-nano, windows, ch340

For some weeks my latest dozen of Nano's isn't recognized any more by Win 10 computer: After two days of experiments I have suspicions:

1. Is there any change in Win10 since all Arduinos now are only shown in "Hidden devices" in the device manager? However, my old Uno and also an old Nano are still working despite of that... (The old nano has a chip named CH340G on the downside; the new nano's chip has no name at all).
2. The Nanos I'm trying to program now I got from China (order date 26 sep 2019) and they are said to be compatible with CH340SER. In fact I have programmed several of them early this year - turning back to them in October, upload was no longer possible.
3. In the meantime, I have switched from Arduino IDE 1.8.6 to 1.8.13 - however, I guess this is not the reason for my troubles since not even Windows recognizes the device when I plug it in...
   Any advices to this problem?
   Dieter

Comment: With Chinese clones the best one can ever say is "Maybe..." - and it sounds like you have a clone of a clone - so the best one can say there is "um... probably not...!"

Comment: You're lucky it's worked this long.  You get what you pay for. Pay for crud and you get crud.

Comment: I've had the same troubles - but it's not Windows 10 being the guilty part.
What kind of Arduino are you using? If it's a Nano (i.e. ATmega328P) then try
selecting "Nano (Old bootloader)" - this works - at least for me.
Regards Dieter